# Log for Successful deliveries are not listed in CloudWatchLog

Tags: amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Integrated AWS-SNS for sending SMS. Configured the Text message preference as per the [AWS Document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html)

I am able to view the CloudWatchLog for failed deliveries as per the below image. But I am  not able to view the log for successful deliveries. Where I can view the log for Successful deliveries?
[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

In SNS, under "Manage text messaging preferences", check the value of "Default percentage of success to sample".  If it is set to 0, that will cause only Failures to go to CloudWatch.  Set it to 100 if you'd like all successes to be logged.

Per [AWS's Viewing Amazon CloudWatch Metrics and Logs for SMS Deliveries document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html):

> For Default percentage of success to sample, specify the percentage of successful SMS deliveries for which Amazon SNS will write logs in CloudWatch Logs. For example, to write logs only for failed deliveries, set this value to 0. To write logs for 10% of your successful deliveries, set it to 10. If you don't specify a percentage, Amazon SNS writes logs for all successful deliveries.